# Change the Marker based on Temperature

Tags: dictionary, icons, google-maps-markers, google-fusion-tables, temperature

I have a sample fusion table map here http://jsfiddle.net/qEGpz/ 
I want to set the marker to red_stars based on temperature >75 degree. But my code doesn't work correctly. Link to my fusion table is here https://www.google.com/fusiontables/DataSource?snapid=S567077W7iF Anyone please help. Thank you in advance.

With regards,
*Pradeep Shankar M*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example seems to be working fine.  What is the problem?  Note: the red_stars icon is fairly subtle. Looks like a standard Google Maps red marker with a black center star vs. black center circle.

Here's the list of the allowed Fusion Table [iconNames](https://www.google.com/fusiontables/DataSource?dsrcid=308519). Choose Visualize -> Map to see what they look like.  Perhaps you need to use "capital_small_highlight".

Took another look and another guess as what your problem is.  Try this:

```
layer8 = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
    query: {
      select: 'Geometry',
      from: '4080901',
      where: "Temp >= 75"
    },
    styles: [ {
      where: "Temp >= '75'",
      markerOptions: {
        iconName: "red_stars",
      }
    }]
  });
  layer8.setMap(map);
```

Comment: Actually i want the icons whose temperature >75 degree should be red stars. But only 3 points have red stars in map but there is 8 points in FT whose temp is more than 75 degree.

Comment: I also tried this code by removing control as `var layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
  query: {
   select: "Geometry",
          from: "4080901"
        },
        styles: [{
  markerOptions: {
 iconName: "",
   }
  },{
          where: "Temp < 40",
          markerOptions: {
            iconName: "grn_stars",
   }
  }, {
  where: "Temp >= 40 && Temp < 75",
 markerOptions: {
  iconName: "ylw_stars",
    }
  }, {
  where: "Temp >= 75",
   markerOptions: {
   iconName: "red_stars",
          }
  }]
 }); 
 layer.setMap(map);
  }` But it is also not working. Plz help.

Comment: There is a problem with your table. Chose Visualize->Table->options. Select Temp, select >, enter 75 then Apply.  Only 4 rows are returned one of which seems to have a bad kml location field.

Comment: But why the Temp above 100 is not dispalying on map?

Comment: Go to your Fusion Table, chose Edit->Modify Column and make sure that FT thinks it's  a number.  Try manually updating the Temp values.

Comment: Yes... Initially it is text and i changed it to Number. Now works fine. Thanks alot for your help.